# Meaning of "The dresses were a spray of light. The men’s trousers hit the shoe just right."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> ‘People danced there, in the daytime, in the middle of the morning, down
> the aisle between the two long rows of tables. The songs they favoured
> were South American ones with titles the Australians passed over in
> ignorance, thinking them Italian: the songs were more passionate, more
> driven, more intellectual than anything we know of here. They danced in
> each other’s arms, with their elbows up high and no expression on their
> faces: it was all form and precision. They did the tango, the rhumba, the
> samba. They knew the steps. They never stumbled. Their arms and legs
> were long and sinewy. **The dresses were a spray of light. The men’s trousers
> hit the shoe just right.**

maybe it was dark and because of the lights that were there their dresses seemed to be a spray of light. and the man trousers hit the shoe **straight**. Am I right?

Does "just right" mean: regularly in rhyme of songs.

Source: The Children's Bach by Helen Garner

Comment: I edited my question, I would be thankful if anyone could help me. As a non-native some details is unclear to me.

Comment: It wasn't dark - the first sentence says it was _in the daytime, in the middle of the morning_. Presumably the author means that the women's white or brightly coloured skirts looked like flashes of light as they swirled around. I don't know what she meant by _just right_ - perhaps that the trousers were just the right length to look elegant.

Comment: As a non-native the meaning of "just right" is unclear to me and I thought his trousers were ironed and they hit the shoe in 90 angle. I don't expect negative point. I am thankful if anyone could tell me the meaning of "just right". Does "right" here is an adverb?

Comment: Are you wearing trousers? Are they too long, too short or **just right**? :). I don't like my coffee too hot or too cool. I like it "just right". That is an idiom. "To be just right" refers to the condition of a thing in reference to a person's tastes.

Comment: I would interpret "just right" as meaning "exactly the way they should."  However, knowing how pants "should" hit the shoes really depends on knowing what was stylish or fashionable at that time and place. In this context, it's impossible to know whether that means "at 90-degree angle" or "with a slight break" - all we know is that it means "in the way that is fashionable right now."

Comment: @CanadianYankee He doesn't know the idiom: to be just right, don't you see? He thinks  **right** refers to an angle. It does not. Gees.

Comment: Oh, I see. _Just right_ is a well-established expression meaning _in exactly the right way_ or _exactly what was needed_. It has nothing to do with right angles. We can only guess why the author describes the men's trousers in that way.

Comment: A literal spray of light is light spilling out of some crack or opening. In a ballroom it might be the sunlight streaming in the windows and creating white patches on the floor. The author is comparing the brightly-colored, possible white dresses of the ladies to such an effect.